# Trying to save a graph in R, but the file is too big. Trying to shrink it

Tags: r, plot, graph, save, data-science

I need to save a graph to a word document in order to submit it to a medical journal. When I paste my graph into Word, the resolution is not great and it says it's scales to 22% of the original size. When I save it using an R code, the resolution is great. However, it appears that the image is quite big when I save it. If I change the scale to 100% of the original size in word, it is way too big for the document (but is clear).

I am using the following code to save it:

```
jpeg("filename.jpg", units="in", width=7, height=7, res=300)

CODE FOR PLOT

dev.off()
```

The journal requires at least 300dpi. The issue is likely that 7x7 is just too big because when I scale it down and insert it into word, it is very clear. However, I can't scale it down to anything lower than 7x7 because it will cut off parts of my plot.

How do I fix this situation? I would like to scale down the plot so it's a smaller size, without losing any resolution and cutting off any part of the graph.

Answer (score 0):

I would submit the graph as 300dpi in the size you are happy with and the journal will be able to deal with it.

However, if you want to change height etc I would do the following:

```
tiff("test.tiff", width = 2700, height = 1600, units = 'px', res = 300)
plot(iris$Sepal.Length, iris$Petal.Length)
dev.off()

#OR different width height

tiff("test2.tiff", width = 700, height = 1000, units = 'px', res = 300)
plot(iris$Sepal.Length, iris$Petal.Length)
dev.off()
```